# what is the best approach for the project which has to operate on more than 50 excel files and each file contains an average of 25k lines

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, apache-poi

what is the best approach for the project which has to operate on more than 50 excel files and each file contains an average of 25k lines.

project description:
I have to load the data (3 columns from each file) and store them in arrays and use them for different calculations. I am using the poi library for handling excel files. when  i try to load the data there is an error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

let me know the approach to avoid the GC overhead error.

```
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {
    Date date;
    static int temp = 0;

    static ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException, ParseException {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Shiva\\Downloads\\ISEC\\IS");
        System.out.println(f.list().length);
        int count = 0;
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                count++;
                userlist.add(new User());
                String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = file.getAbsolutePath();
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                int[] oct = new int[sheet.getLastRowNum()];
                int[] dur = new int[sheet.getLastRowNum()];
                long[] frstrealpt = new long[sheet.getLastRowNum()];
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
                int z = 0;
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                        continue; //just skip the rows if row number is 0
                    }
                    Cell pkts = row.getCell(2);
                    Cell octets = row.getCell(3);
                    oct[z] = (int) octets.getNumericCellValue();

                    Cell duration = row.getCell(9);
                    dur[z] = (int) duration.getNumericCellValue();

                    Cell realfrstpkt = row.getCell(6);
                    frstrealpt[z] = (long) realfrstpkt.getNumericCellValue();


                    z++;

                }
                System.out.println(oct.length);


            }

        }

        System.out.println(userlist.size());


    }

}
```

Comment: You might try to close `Workbook` objects after you've done with them. But you might also start JVM with more memory.

Comment: You might also consider using VB. It's rather better than Java for this kind of thing, as it doesn't need its own POI library.

Comment: In general load only the data you need in the moment rather than loading all data at the start of the program.

Comment: @EJP: I don't know how this comment shall be helpful here. If `VB` "doesn't need its own library" for reading `Excel`, then it needs `Excel` being installed on the system. Also it is limited to Windows systems. So "VB is rather better than Java for this kind of thing" is simply a wrong statement in my opinion.